# mod after a function

Tags: math-software, maple

I am trying to find the solution, null space, for a set of equations represented by a matrix A.  The example I find is as follows:

Nullspace(A) mod 5;

I have two questions:

1 - I cannot get Maple to give me numbers it just displays the command with the Matrix in brackets.  Not being able to display numbers is a common problem for me, and many times when I am doing assignments, I need numbers.  I find this very frustrating, as I would like to make maximum use of Maple.

2- What does the mod extension do in this case.  I have searched the help files and can find similar examples like Factor(x^3+2) mod 5; but I do not know what the mod extension does, nor can I find a reasonable explanation.  Again quite frustrating.

I appreciate any help that can be offered.

Comment: I don't think this question belongs here but in some software related site.

Comment: There are a ton of Maple questions on this site, and Maple is purely a math software.

Comment: When queried just for `Nullspace` the Maple help system brings up http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Nullspace  instead of the more commonly needed http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=LinearAlgebra/NullSpace help page. This is an unfortunate weakness (bug).

Comment: @DonAntonio I asked on meta concerning the limits of questions concerning mathematical software [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4974/the-limit-of-questions-concerning-mathematical-software) and the (limited) consensus seemed to be that they were fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the meaning of `mod 5`, then you probably are not doing [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). You probably want to use the command `NullSpace`. About which you should notice two things:

- it requires LinearAlgebra package
- commands are case-sensitive, so NullSpace is not the same as Nullspace.

Here is an example taken directly from the help file on LinearAlgebra[NullSpace]. Notice that the matrix is entered column by column.

[image: NullSpace example]